# Power Query: Find minimum value over multiple columns but ignoring 0 and null

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a rather simple problem in Power Query, but I couldn't find the solution yet. I want to have an additional column with the minimum value of the other columns. But some of them contain 0 values, which I want to ignore.
Like This:
[image]

Is there an easy way with List.Min() or with a conditional column to solve this?
And additional is it also possible to ignore null values? (But only needed if it does not make it more complex)

I tried something with List.Min(). Until now I just get errors or just a TRUE/FALSE like in this example:
`Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Min", each List.Min({[A]>0, [B]>0, [C]>0, [D]>0}), type number)`
I don't want to have a huge if/else statement because there are more columns than in the example above. Also I am not intrested in grouping or changing the dataset.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"C", Int64.Type}, {"D", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Min( List.RemoveItems( List.RemoveNulls( Record.ToList(_)), {0})))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: That's nice, but what if there are also unnecessary columns which I don't want to include? Let's say I have 20 columns and I only want to extract the minimum value out of 4 of them? Somehow it should be between Records.ToList() right? But that didn't work..

Comment: You didn't specify that in your original question but the solution is similar. Instead of using Record.ToList, just specify the columns you want to check as a list.

Comment: Thanks, now it worked.
`Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Min(List.RemoveItems(List.RemoveNulls({[A],[B],[C],[D]}), {0}))`